# Authenticated youtube.videos.list no longer returns duplicate videos

Tags: youtube-api

When V3 API was released, an authenticated youtube.videos.list API call would return all videos on a users account, including public, private, unlisted, duplicate, failed, and otherwise rejected videos. This was great and essential for us because we upload videos via the API, and we need to be able to detect which videos failed to process or were duplicates, and return an appropriate message to our users.

It would appear however that a recent change to the youtube API has changed this behaviour, as an authenticated youtube.videos.list API call now only returns public, private, & unlisted videos that processed successfully. Therefore, we currently have no way to retrieve the status of failed or duplicate videos. The API will return 0 items instead.

CURL Request:

```
curl -X GET -H "content-length: 0" -H "user-agent: Yt::Request (gzip)" -H "authorization: Bearer [PRIVATE]" -H "host: www.googleapis.com" "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=HI9rw_xzem4&part=status"
```

Actual Response:

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
 "etag": "\"XpPGQXPnxQJhLgs6enD_n8JR4Qk/FOlClkGrlyfelgsmQeQKjpA_2DQ\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 0,
  "resultsPerPage": 0
 },
 "items": []
}
```

Expected Response:

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
 "etag": "\"XpPGQXPnxQJhLgs6enD_n8JR4Qk/IffXqYgL0_RqhHktOol1wW-rUvo\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 1,
  "resultsPerPage": 1
 },
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#video",
   "etag": "\"XpPGQXPnxQJhLgs6enD_n8JR4Qk/ffSgsvaN6HpnGWEKitI6q-NtGDk\"",
   "id": "HI9rw_xzem4",
   "status": {
    "uploadStatus": "duplicate",
    "privacyStatus": "unlisted",
    "license": "youtube",
    "embeddable": true,
    "publicStatsViewable": true
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

I've filed a bug report here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/129270261

Does anyone know of any workarounds in the meantime?